# Randomly "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'IP' (4)"

Tags: networking, mysql

I have a server (server A) that does a SQL Query every 30 seconds to another server (server B) (both of them are dedicated servers that I own). But randomly, and not the 100% of the time, Server A gets:

```
[2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (4)
```

or

```
[2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
```

Sample log file:

```
08/02/2019 - 04:37:17: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:37:47: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:38:17: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:38:47: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:39:17: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:39:47: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:40:17: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:40:47: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:41:17: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:41:47: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:42:17: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:42:47: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:43:17: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:43:46: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:44:18: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:44:48: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:45:18: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:45:48: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:46:27: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (4)
08/02/2019 - 04:46:49: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:47:27: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (4)
08/02/2019 - 04:47:57: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (4)
08/02/2019 - 04:48:17: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:48:47: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:49:17: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:49:47: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:50:17: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:50:47: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:51:17: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:51:47: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:52:17: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:52:48: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:53:18: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:53:48: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:54:18: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:54:48: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:55:18: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:55:48: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:56:17: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:56:47: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:57:18: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:57:47: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:58:17: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:58:47: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (101)
08/02/2019 - 04:59:18: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 04:59:48: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 05:00:18: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 05:00:48: Rows returned: 405
08/02/2019 - 05:01:18: Rows returned: 405

...

08/02/2019 - 22:07:57: Rows returned: 410
08/02/2019 - 22:08:27: Rows returned: 410
08/02/2019 - 22:08:58: Rows returned: 410
08/02/2019 - 22:09:39: [2013]: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
08/02/2019 - 22:10:06: [2003]: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'x.x.x.x' (4)
08/02/2019 - 22:10:27: Rows returned: 410
08/02/2019 - 22:10:57: Rows returned: 410
08/02/2019 - 22:11:27: Rows returned: 410
```

Where x.x.x.x is the IP of Server B.

The server B doesn't have any firewall rules, and MySQL server is running all the time because I can connect from workbench from my PC and I can connect to the website that is running PHP + MySQL.

I tested with another server (server C) to connect to server B but the problem continues, so I think the problem is in Server B but I don't know what to do.

The weird think is that I ran Server A and Server C simultaneously and sometimes Server A got this problem while Server C worked perfectly, and viceversa.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a network issue. Are these servers located in a LAN or is it situated in different regions / locations? How is the connection established? Is it over your public WAN interface or a VPN? Also when your script executes, can you try running a continuous ping from all servers between each other to see if there is any packet drops? There could be many reason..

VK

Comment: Servers are located in differents regions (MySQL server is located in North America and the others, including me, in South America). I'm not using VPN, all is public. I will try pinging continously and update then. Thanks for your reply.